# Getting the "deepest" elements that meet two different descendant selector criteria

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, filtering, dom-traversal

I'm writing a userscript which detects "ship to" arbitrarily designed address forms and parses their contents. In order to do this, I need to find form "rows" (which may or may not be `tr` elements) that contain both the label for the address (such as "Name", "Address1", etc) and the corresponding `input` field for that tag. For example, in the following snippet:

```
<div>
<label>MaidenName</label>
<table><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><label>FirstName</label></td>
        <td><input value = "Bob"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>LastName</label></td>
        <td><input value = "Smith"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>CompanyName</label></td>
        <td><input value = "Ink Inc"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

I would want to match all of the `tr` elements, because they each contain a "Name" label and an input field. However, I would not want to match the `div` on account of the "MaidenName" label, because it has broader scope than the matches found for the fields inside of the table.

My current algorithm to find these rows (which are often `div` elements instead of `tr` ones) is to:

- Find all the nodes with appropriate "Name" labels
- Working my way up the DOM for each node until I find a node that is an ancestor of an input field
- Then remove the children I traversed to get there, leaving only the parent elements of the set.

Translating from the port I'm working in, the JQuery Javascript would look like the following:

```
// set up my two lists
var labelNodes = getLabelNodes();
var nodesWithAddress = 
    $().find("input[type='text']:visible, select:visible");

var pathToCommonParents = getLabelNodes()
    .parentsUntil(nodesWithAddressChildren.parents()).parent();

// keep the highest-level nodes, so we only have the common paths - 
//not the nodes between it and the labels.
return combinedNodeSet.filter(
    function (index) {return $(this).find(combinedNodeSet).length == 0});
```

This works... but all of that traversing and comparing overhead absolutely wrecks my performance (this can take *five seconds* or more.)

What would be a better way of implementing this? I think the following pseudocode would be better, but I could be wrong, and I don't know how to implement it:

```
var filteredSet = $().find(*).hasAnyOf(labelNodes).hasAnyOf(nodesWithAddress);
return filteredSet.hasNoneOf(filteredSet);
```

Comment: Is there always an element like in this case the `td` around the label and the input?

Comment: Always some element, but the nesting depth and tag names around the wrapping element vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to generalize micha's answer so that it can look in a page-independent way (different tags and nesting levels):

```
var labelNodes = getLabelNodes();
var returnNodes = $();

var regexAncestors = labelNodes.parent();

while (regexAncestors.length){
    regexAncestors = regexAncestors.not("body");
    var commonParentNodes = regexAncestors.has("input[type='text']:visible, select:visible");
    returnNodes.add(commonParentNodes);
    regexAncestors = regexAncestors.not(commonParentNodes).parent();
}
return returnNodes;
```

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

I've found a better solution (see revisions) I think this will work prefectly for you.

```
function getMySpeacialElements() {
    var aSpeacialElements = [];
    $("label").each(function() {
        var oParent = $(this).parent(),
            oSpeacial = oParent.parent();
        oSpeacial.children("*").each(function() {
            if ($(this).children("input").length) {
                aSpeacialElements.push(oSpeacial[0]);
            }
        });
    });
    return aSpeacialElements;
}
```

​

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EL7CZ/2/)**

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'll be able to figure out how this works if I sit down for five minutes, but future SO readers (not to mention myself) may benefit from an overview of what's going on.

Comment: He looks at every label on the page, as its iterating through, the label is set as the parent. Then he looks at all the children and finds that ones that are inputs. Once an input is found, he pushes that element into an array. Very good approach.